# Pressure Sensor connets 2 stage opamp but i didn't identify it

Tags: operational-amplifier, identification

I must copy a circuit and top of that it has a pressure sensor and this image shows connection. I think that it connects 2 stage Op-Amp but i didn't identify Op-Amp. Can anybody help me.

[image]

This is 2 stage Op-Amp or different circuit component i didn't understand

[image]

Pin Connection;

Pressure Sensor pin-1 connects BIM-79Z2 pin-3

Pressure Sensor pin-5 connects BIM-79Z2 pin-1

Pressure Sensor pin-6 connects BIM-79Z2 pin-5

Pressure Sensor pin-3 connects BIM-79Z2 pin-2

My Question is i didn't find something like that 2 stage Op-Amp every 2 stage opamp input pins 2,3,5,6 and output pins 1,7 what kind of 2-Stage Op-Amp is this?

Answer (score 3):

Your part number is [INA337AIDGKT](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/INA337AIDGKT/296-13453-1-ND/486365) Here is a link to the [Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina337.pdf)

Comment: Please try to include a bit of the IC detail into your answer with the edit button. Manufacturer and IC name and type would be good. Some supporting evidence would be "pinout matches the description" or top code matches etc. For ex, OP is confused about what type of IC it is, and while the links answer that, we like to include that info here for clarity. Thanks and +1